# remove double quotes from variable in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Here is my MVC code:

```
public JsonResult GetRemix()
{
        List<Intractive_ReMixList_ForScreenShot> employee = new List<Intractive_ReMixList_ForScreenShot>();
        string query = string.Format("Select * From Intractive_ReMixList_ForScreenShot where LoginDetailsRowId=80136");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ITALIAGRP_DATA\DATASERVER;Initial Catalog=StorageManagerNew;User ID=internal;Password=c@rlos150915; Timeout=30000");
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    employee.Add(
                        new Intractive_ReMixList_ForScreenShot
                        {

                            ChipID = int.Parse(reader["ChipID"].ToString()),

                            ImageName =(reader["ImageName"].ToString()),
                            RandNo = int.Parse(reader["RandNo"].ToString())
                        }
                    );
                }
            }

            return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Here is an image of the employee object:

[image]

I want to remove the double quotes from `ImageName`. In the above image the value is in double quoted form - How can I remove this?

Here is the jQuery code which calls the action method:

```
 $.ajax({             
            url: "Home/GetRemix",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                debugger;
                var rows;
                for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                    var row = $('<tr style="height:30px;width:30px;"></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                    $.each(data, function (k, item) {

                        debugger;
                        for (var j = 0; j < cols;) {
                            debugger;
                            $('<td style="border:2px solid #FFF;"><img class="slide" style="width:30px; height:30px;" id="img' + item.RandNo + '" src=img/tiles/"' +item.ImageName+ '"></td>').appendTo(row);
                           j++;
                        }
                    });

               // $('#TableID tbody').append(rows);
                mytable.appendTo("#TableID");
                }       
            },
            error: function (data) {
                debugger;
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

In this jQuery code `item.ImageName` gives an error because of the quotation - the image is not found in the path, just because of the double quotation.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: There are no double quotes in image name. Actually it's Visual Studio that shows double quotes because it's string.

Comment: I never understood why people make the effort to post on SO before trying to understand their own code (and tools in this case) ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is yet another "Quotes in C#" question that is looking for a solution to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Please have someone proof-read your question. It's completely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is not in the server-side or anything related to Visual Studio or .NET (strings have quotes round them, that's how they're written, and so that's how they're shown in the debugger), but in your JS code:

```
src=img/tiles/"' +item.ImageName+ '"
```

is adding quotes in the wrong place, and producing an invalid HTML element.

This simple demo illustrates the issue by showing the incorrect HTML produced by your code:

```js
var item = { "ImageName": "9714_1_4", "RandNo": 1};
var str = '<td style="border:2px solid #FFF;"><img class="slide" style="width:30px; height:30px;" id="img' + item.RandNo + '" src=img/tiles/"' +item.ImageName+ '"></td>';

alert(str);
```

To fix, you simply need to move the double-quote in your code to the start of the value you're defining for the "src" attribute, so that the whole path is contained in the quotes (and thus becomes a valid attribute):

```
src="img/tiles/' +item.ImageName+ '"
```

```js
var item = { "ImageName": "9714_1_4", "RandNo": 1};
var str = '<td style="border:2px solid #FFF;"><img class="slide" style="width:30px; height:30px;" id="img' + item.RandNo + '" src="img/tiles/' +item.ImageName+ '"></td>';

alert(str);
```

Of course it may be that your image name also needs a file extension (e.g. ".jpg" or something) as well to make it point to an actual file on the server, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: While that seems to be the right answer, I would generally discourage answering obviously bad questions, or to put it bluntly: This question doesn't *deserve* an answer. Everything about it is bad and getting an answer will not encourage the author to do better the next time they want to ask something. Instead, if you haven't already, I suggest you down- and close-vote this question.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Respectfully I disagree. It's true that the grammar is not great (I'd assume that's just due to language barrier, a friendly edit could help with that), but there's code shown, a picture of the "issue", and a just-about-comprehensible description of what goes wrong. The problem was diagnosable from that. I've seen a lot worse. The issue may have been totally unrelated to the OP's assumptions, and they maybe have misunderstood the nature of the tools they use and some basics about string variables, but hopefully they will learn something from this.